# store and retrieve value for multiple select in a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a jquery function designed to make form values persistent by setting a cookie for each value and populating the field from it on page load.

It looks like this:

```
$(function () {

var bindToCookie = function (identifier, alias) {
    var timetoKeep = 7;
    var readVal = CookieManager.readCookie(alias);
    //console.log(identifier + 'value = ' + readVal);
    if (readVal) {
        //console.log(identifier + 'value set= ' + readVal);
        $(identifier).val(readVal);
    }

    $(identifier).on('change', function () {
        CookieManager.createCookie(alias, $(identifier).val(), timetoKeep);
    });
};

bindToCookie('#todatepicker', 'todate');
bindToCookie('#fromdatepicker', 'fromdate');
bindToCookie('#languagepicker', 'language');
bindToCookie('#stationpicker', 'station');
bindToCookie('#programpicker', 'program');
bindToCookie('#sourcepicker', 'sourcepicker');

});
```

This is working fine for all of my single values, but the field '#sourcepicker' is a multiple select, and it only works as expected when a single value is selected. For example if I select value 1, it loads with 1 selected, but if I select 1 and 4, the cookie is saved with a value of 1,4 and nothing is selected on reload. I seem to be able to set multiple value for it in jquery using the syntax $('#sourcepicker').val(["1","4"]); Whereas if I do $('#sourcepicker').val([1,4]);

How do I reformat this function to correctly store and retrieve values for the multiple select in a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

A multi-select returns a string (comma-separated list) of the selected values - you need to write an optional bit of code that deals with the comma-separated list when it finds it in the cookie:

```
if (readVal.indexOf(",") > -1) {
    /* make an an array out of readVal,
       select the options in the multi-select
       and so on */
}
```

Comment: So Im not sure how to format the value in the cookie. After making a multiple selection and doing $('#sourcepicker').val(); in the console I get ["1", "8"] in the console. If I set the cookie to ["1", "8"] $('#sourcepicker').val(); returns null.

Comment: I would try to work with the value in the cookie as it is, breaking it into it's component parts after retrieval.